# VueRouter - localStorage gets cleared when no trailing slash is added in URL

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, vue-router

I use localStorage to store a JWT-token.

When I go to https://www.example.com/my-web-app/, I can see the JWT token in the Developer Tools --> Application.
When I go to https://www.example.com/my-web-app, no data in the localStorage is visible.

This means that user of the application has to log in over and over again if he doesn't add a trailing slash to the URL.
Anyone have an idea where the cause might be?

**Dependencies**

```json
{
   "vue": "^2.6.11",
   "vue-router": "^3.1.5"
}
```

**VueRouter config:**

```js
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
    }
},
{
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
}
```

**htaccess config** *(located in /my-web-app)*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /my-web-app/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /my-web-app/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a utility function that auto add the trailing slash on every route when is not :

**util.js**

```
export function trailingSlash (str) {
  return str.endsWith('/') ? str : str + '/'
}
```

in the router file,
**router/index.js**

```
    import { trailingSlash } from 'util.js'
    ...
    ...
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        return to.path.endsWith('/') ? next() : next(trailingSlash(to.path))
    })
```

A trailing slash is going to be added a the end of the url.

Comment: This gives this error:
`Error: Redirected when going from "/page2/" to "/page1" via a navigation guard.`

Comment: Besides, I guess the problem is already happening even before the user enters the Vue application. Could we force this at the htaccess level?

Comment: yeah i guess is better

Comment: # Force Trailing Slash

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

Comment: The problem doesn't occur in [hash mode](https://beluxvacc.org/adids-staging/#/acc). Only in history mode. Thanks for the htaccess snippet. Can you give me the complete snippet? I guess it needs to be mixed with the original of VueRouter: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232269/discussion-between-edouard-yonga-and-studio-pj).

Comment: For the followers of this question; The issue is not solved yet.